# How to set labels in matplotlib.hlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to put labels for each line in matplotlib.hlines:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hlines(y=1, xmin=1, xmax=4, label='somelabel1')
plt.hlines(y=2, xmin=2, xmax=5, label='somelabel2')
```

I need a plot with two horizintal lines with labels on 'y' axis for each line.
Instead of it I get a plot without labels, with only coordinates (see the sample image). Is it possible to put lables for each line into the plot?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `label` `kwarg` is to specify the string that's displayed in a `legend`, not necessarily on the line itself. If you want the label to appear in your plot, you'll want to use a [`text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) object instead

```
plt.hlines(y=1, xmin=1, xmax=4)
plt.text(4, 1, ' somelabel1', ha='left', va='center')

plt.hlines(y=2, xmin=2, xmax=5)
plt.text(2, 2, 'somelabel2 ', ha='right', va='center')
```

[image]

If you instead want special y axis labels for these, you can use a custom formatter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

plt.hlines(y=1, xmin=1, xmax=4)
plt.hlines(y=2, xmin=2, xmax=5)

def formatter(y, pos):
    if y == 1:
        return 'label1'
    elif y == 2:
        return 'label2'
    else:
        return y

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(formatter))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Is it possible to replace y coordinates with those string labels?

Comment: @Vlad I'm not sure what you mean. Like the y axis labels?

Comment: Yes, to put 'somelabel1' insted of '1.0' on the y axis, 'somelabel2' instead of '2.0' etc. May be I chose a wrong type of plot, though I didn't find anything that fit more for my purpose (